# Ubuntu Screen Flickering after Changing Brightness

Tags: 12.04, brightness, acer, flicker

I have an Acer Aspire 5742G latop with Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS.
Firstly I had a problem with the brightness (I couldn't change it) but afer I changed `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` value to:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux"`

the brightness problem was solved.

But now when I change the brightness by pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>left arrow</kbd>/<kbd>right arrow</kbd>, all the windows that are open starts flickering and every time I press any button they flicker again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved!

After Changing brightness screen stops flickering if I press Alt + SysRq + r.

http://www.howtogeek.com/119127/use-the-magic-sysrq-key-on-linux-to-fix-frozen-x-servers-cleanly-reboot-and-run-other-low-level-commands/